# log4j2 appending the few entries of current day log in previous log file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

**This is my scenario:**
   For my website I have used **log4j2** for rolling log files. currently I am generating 3 log file which consist of 2 rolling file (trace & error) and 1 routing appender.

1) Trace log of entire date (rolling file appender)

2) Error log of entire date (rolling file appender)

3) logged users activity log for entire day (routing file appender)

Below is my **log4j2.xml** using for the above scenario, which works exactly as per the requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="WARN" name="mywebsite" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger{1}] - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="error-log" append="true"
            fileName="D:/client/error [${date:yyyy-MM-dd}].log" filePattern="D:/lient/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger{1}] - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="trace-log" append="true"
            fileName="D:/client/trace [${date:yyyy-MM-dd}].log" filePattern="D:/client/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger{1}] - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFileName}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:logFileName}" append="true"
                        fileName="D:/userlog/${ctx:logFileName}~${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                        filePattern="D:/userlog/${date:yyyy-MM}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout
                            pattern="[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger{1}] - %msg%n" />
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
                <Route ref="Console" key="${ctx:logFileName}" />
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace" additivity="false">
            <Appender-Ref ref="Console"/> 
            <Appender-Ref ref="trace-log" level="trace" />
            <Appender-Ref ref="error-log" level="error" />
            <Appender-Ref ref="RoutingAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am new to log4j, I somehow managed to configure the log4j xml from the sources in internet.
 Rolling file  were created for every day and file append-er created for each user and catches the respective events in the respective files for the entire day, until a new file rolls out on next day.

**Issue is :**

When a new file rolls on, few events of current day were added in the previous day log file.

For example the **trace.log** file of 1st November has the few log events(say around 5-10 lines) entries of 2nd November.

This happens for file append-er too .

For example file append-er will generate log file based on user log's in say log file named **john-01-112015.log** was created yesterday. and same user log's in 2nd November a new file will be rolled out as per the configuration. but the few logs of 2nd November is added in the **john-01-112015.log** as said in the previous scenario.

Is there anything wrong in the log4j2.xml ? guys help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of log4j 2 did you use?

Comment: You may have found a bug. Please raise this on the log4j Jira issue tracker.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: @Remko popma I am using log4j 2.1 version. i think it might be a bug in this version. will upgrade to the latest version and check..

Comment: @RemkoPopma the issue still exist . it happens again now. i do know what done wrong in xml ..